# JRuby Embed Should I instantiate one ScriptingContainer per request?

Tags: jruby

I'm embedding JRuby in a java library on a web application using concurrent mode (Single Ruby Runtime), should instantiate one ScriptingContainer per request, or reuse the same instance of the ScriptingContainer in all requests ?

Comment: I'd take a look at the jruby/rack interface for inspiration...